# One Hot Encoding with many categories

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a categorical data set which I am trying to convert it to numerical format. I did try generic one hot encoding but it resulted in huge dimensions. So I am limiting my encoding to top 8 categories in each parameter.

So I am looping through each column. But I am getting an error at data_prep_text.i.value_counts.

```
for i in data_prep_text.columns:
    if len(data_prep_text[i].unique())>7:
        top8=[j for j in data_prep_text.i.value_counts(ascending=False.head(8)).index]
        for label in top8:
            data_prep_text[label]=np.where(data_prep_text[i]==label,1,0)
    else:
        data_prep_text[i]=0
```

This is the error I am facing:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-e25949bef086> in <module>
      1 for i in data_prep_text.columns:
      2     if len(data_prep_text[i].unique())>7:
----> 3         top8=[j for j in data_prep_text.i.value_counts(ascending=False.head(8)).index]
      4         for label in top8:
      5             data_prep_text[label]=np.where(data_prep_text[i]==label,1,0)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4374             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4375                 return self[name]
-> 4376             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4377 
   4378     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i'
```

'''

If i is taking 'Neighborhood'.
The code is not taking i value and making it like data_prep_text.Neighborhood.value_counts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the bracket notation to avoid this problem and to remove the `head` method and replace it by taking the first 8 values using slicing

```
top8=[j for j in data_prep_text[i].value_counts(ascending=False)[:8].index]
```

When you do `data_prep_text.i` it is the equivalent of `data_prep_text['i']`.

Comment: But still I am getting error Attribute error: 'bool' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: You can't take head inside of `value_counts`, but you can get the first eight indices by doing `[:8]`, I have updated my answer